# How to outrank well reputed Websites?

Tags: seo, google

I have already read [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google) and applied almost every on-page SEO advice from the answers to that question.

One of my site (internal link) ranks on the second page of Google, with really high competitive keywords (two-word keywords).

When I analyzed all the links on the first page, many sites are 5 to 15 years old. Forbes, Entrepreneur, Neil Patel and Yahoo also is on the first page for that keyword.

My site is just 1 year old and I have done everything that I know to make to On-Page SEO better.

But I don't think that On-Page SEO is enough to outrank these big sites.
Is there anything I could do, to be in first 1-3 results in such type of situation?

I mean how can I outrank these big sites like Forbes, Entrepreneur, Neil Patel, Yahoo? Or should I give up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should i give up? - Absolutely not.

Big guys may rank higher but probably they might not be as focused as you considering they might have many things to worry about. And here you got a chance.

Yes, true just rich content might not be good enough to beat tough competition. But you need to have patience and continue to work hard.

Bring the point of difference in your page content and prove yours one is better than others.

Then market them on social media and let people link naturally.

There is nothing better than other people linking to your article naturally and see the magic in ranking return.

So, never give up, come back to this every now and then see what extra new thing you can bring and keep building.

Answer (score 1):

Try a data set, or a few, related to your industry with a report about it, or an informative infographic that are often shared via social media. And remember, a good story, either entertainment or one to educate, with a splash of reference about famous people or historic events even, will have word combinations that help you out if/when searchers retry their searches with different word combinations frustrated themselves that the common terms give them common, rather than unique, sites.  I also understand that momentum from searches in a geographic area can bump up ranking so don't forget to use local focused advertising and try and get in local newspaper stories for local niche traffic which might lead to more rankings for wider geographic reference and relevance with consistency if one area geographic area stays strong. A big or emerging national brand partnership can be of immense help and worth way more than paying for tweaks to site structure or language.

Answer (score 0):

On-page factor is important but not crucial. The number of backlinks is. The more you have from reputable places, the better. Mind, backlinks should also be from topically relevant places, like from the same niche.

Outranking big players is realistic but requires lots of RESEARCH and patience. You should try to take after their week pages. Comparing whole domain's for keywords shall bring small insight into the matter. What you should so is to find their pages that are ranking somewhere between 1st and 10th position range and compare them with your targeted pages. Find their keywords with declined positions and match them with your keywords. If you will regularly monitor such changes in positions, you'll know on which of your currently ranking keywords should you put more stress on (e.g. put more relevance to them in the eyes of SE, like include them in anchor texts for external and internal linking).

That's the only working way that I know of which prings real results. I mean, I managed to rank my half-year-old domain's on top of SERPs that showed Amazon, Wikipeadia and Walmart on them.